# How to deploy an application in Vespa to a remote target using pyvespa?

Tags: python, vespa

I have Vespa running in a container (using Docker compose) and want to deploy my application package from another container in the same network using [pyvespa](https://pyvespa.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). The `vespa deploy` command of [Vespa CLI](https://docs.vespa.ai/en/vespa-cli.html) has a target option where I can provide a host, but I don't see such an option when using pyinvoke. Especially the `Vespa` class has no deploy method. Is this scenario not supported by pyvespa and do I have to use the Vespa CLI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prefer using Vespa CLI for control plane changes. The deploy support in pyvespa is for demonstration purposes (e.g. to demonstrate in a notebook).